# Getting user input and saving it in app memory

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am new here to stackoverflow and a beginner in programming.
I probably have a very basic question for the experienced programmers in C#.

I'm working in Visual Studio WinForms and if you look at the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of the app]

I know the code for getting the user input for First Name, Last Name and Birthday and having it print out in the textbox on the right.
The problem is that I want to add several persons and if I register for another one, it just erases the first person.
Now my question is this:

- How do I store the data in the app (no database is necessary, I just want it to be in the memory of the running app), so I can add several persons and have each one printed out in the textbox in a line of its own.
  Then when I'm done registering persons, I want to have them all printed out, with the push of another button on another page. Kinda like a submission form when you travel, you see all the data you've entered on the last page.

I'm thinking I need to store it in a List or something, and I have tried that, but I can't get it to work (probably not the right syntax).
It's probably very simple, but I am stuck! :(

I hope my question is clear enough.

A huge thank you for any help here :)

Comment: Personally, I would purchase a book about C# programming. I would expect such a book to teach me about collections and the like.

Comment: please post the code where you tried to use the `List`

Comment: When posting, always add what you have tried if you can, It helps make a rounded question which is easier to understand. Also, it will help improve your skill as others will often give you tips

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect answers already. Nice place :)
Thank you for all the suggestions, I will try them out!

Comment: @PeterHanson If one answer helped you to solve your problem, you might want to consider to mark is as correct answer. Check the green check-icon beside the answer. It will help other people who might find your question helpful, and the both of you will gain reputation

Answer (score 2):

Creating a Class to map a Person is a great way to go!

First, you could create a Person.cs file in your project like this:

```
public class Person() {

    public string firstName {get; set;}
    public string lastName {get; set;}
    public string birthday {get; set;}

    public Person(fName, lName, bDay) {
        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
        birthday = bDay;
    }

    // Addition by @MongZhu
    public override ToString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName + " Birthday: " + birthday;
    }

}
```

Next, in your form code, you will want to make a global list like this. put this at the start of your code, or on your `onLoad` event:

```
List<Person> myList = new List<Person>;
```

Make sure you have using `System.Collections.Generic` imported at the top!

Finally, when you click your 'register' button you want to **add** to the list.
This can be done within your `onClick` event for the button:

```
myList.Add(new Person(tbfName.text, tblName.text, tbBirth.text);
```

Now you will have a list that saves people. But you want to print too!
On whatever trigger you wish to print the list, maybe after you have added a new record you can do a `foreach` loop in order to iterate through the list and get the desired information:

```
foreach(Person p in myList) {
    p.firstName // gets first name
    p.lastName  // gets last name
    p.birthday // gets birthday
    p.ToString() // Print all Person details -- Thanks @MongZhu
}
```

**EDIT** 
I've fixed the syntax for the accessors in the Person class as @MongZhu pointed out and also shown how to override the `ToString()` Method in your class to quickly print out all of the persons details.

In your comments you have asked for more clarification as to how to assign this to a label:

The `foreach` code could go on your button's `onClick()` event.
After you have clicked 'Register' the new person will be created and added to the list. After this code you should insert your foreach:

```
// onClick
void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    myList.Add(new Person(tbfName.text, tblName.text, tbBirth.text); // Added person to list

    // Create a string will all the person details
    string full;
    foreach(Person p in myList) {
        full += p.ToString() + " "; // Print all Person details -- Thanks @MongZhu
    }

    // Update the label
    lbDisplay.Text = full;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping a newbie out, I appreciate it!

Comment: Where excactly do I write the foreach code? under the button (that prints out all list data) event?
And how do I print that out to a label for example?
So far I got this:
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        
        List<Person> myList = new List<Person>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
And

private void btnRegisterPerson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myList.Add(new Person(txtFirst.Text, txtLast.Text, txtBirthday.Text));
        }

Comment: Your post does not implement any `getfirstName()` methods. Might be confusing. Why do you implement `private` properties in the `Person` class and then use methods to access your data? Instead of using proper C# properties with a public getter.

Comment: @PeterHanson You can override the [`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx) method in your `Person` class and display all values of on person at once. Have a look at the link.

Comment: @MongZhu You are correct, I will update my answer. Also, overriding the `ToString()` in the `Person` class is an awesome idea for speed.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Person class with your 3 fields and on register you create a new Person object with the inputs that you have an add it to a List that you can hold in your application.
On click on you second button you iterate over the list and print all persons already added.

See something like this of course you have to user your Person class instead of Part:

```
// Create a list of parts.
    List<Part> parts = new List<Part>();

    // Add parts to the list.
    parts.Add(new Part() {PartName="crank arm", PartId=1234});
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "chain ring", PartId = 1334 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "regular seat", PartId = 1434 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "banana seat", PartId = 1444 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "cassette", PartId = 1534 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { PartName = "shift lever", PartId = 1634 });

    // Write out the parts in the list. This will call the overridden ToString method
    // in the Part class.
    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (Part aPart in parts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(aPart);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple :

Create a class of person with 3 properties, firstName,  lastName, birthDay

create a static list of this person class in your project.

```
IList<person> myList = new List<person>():
myList.Add(person, person........);
```

Add data in this list when you register people.

Show output on the right block using that static list, the list will be available till the program is running. You can use that list for all your other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but check out following code snippet:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<object[]> people = new List<object[]>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var person = new object[3];
        person[0] = txtFirstName.Text;
        person[1] = txtLastName.Text;
        person[2] = txtBirthday.Text;

        people.Add(person);

        txtPeople.Text = string.Empty;

        for (var i=0;i<people.Count;i++)
        {
            txtPeople.Text += string.Format("First name:\t{0}", people[i][0].ToString()) + Environment.NewLine;
            txtPeople.Text += string.Format("Last name:\t{0}", people[i][1].ToString()) + Environment.NewLine;
            txtPeople.Text += string.Format("Birthday:\t\t{0}", people[i][2].ToString()) + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtFirstName.Text = "FirstName" + people.Count();
        txtLastName.Text = "LastName" + people.Count();
        txtBirthday.Text = "Birthday" + people.Count();
    }
}
```